# Spring-boot application runs new thread and Tomcat thinks the application has not started

Tags: spring-boot

We are running a Spring-boot webapp on Tomcat. The application starts a new thread and Tomcat then does not recognise that the application has started and will not start any more webapps.

Comment: Spring Boot Starter Web already have builtin tomcat server. Are you using the same for running your application? Can you provide more information on your server configuration? I might be able to help you.

Comment: @SpringBootApplication

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
We are running on a separate Tomcat not the inbuilt one.
Skeleton code
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan
    public class MyApplication {

```
public static void main (..) {
    startup(..)
}

publc static void startup(applicationBuilder) {

applicationBuilder.run();

Thread ABC new Thread(new ABCThread());
ABC.start();
}
```

this second thread causes the issue.
Also in context.xml we configure spring.config.location which is not picked up when we start the second thread but is picked up if the secong thread is commented out.  Hope that helps.